# Why does binary search algorithm not work?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I've copied code from the book "grokking algorithms" for finding an item in the list using the binary search algorithm. The code launches great and returns no errors. However, sometimes it just doesn't work for certain numbers, for example if i call it to find "1". What's wrong?

```
def binary_search(list, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(list) - 1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high)/2
        guess = list[mid]
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid + 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return None

list1 = []

for i in range (1, 101):
    list1.append(i)

print(list1)
print(binary_search(list1, 1))
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend learning how to use a GUI debugger, like Pycharm's, to figure out exactly how your program executes, since that'd make it trivial to understand the issue in not just this code, but almost any code.

Comment: Are you using python2? `(low + high)/2` should return a float in python3 which will crash your program as floats cannot be used as indices. So if you're using python2, start with upgrading to python3, as python2 is no longer supported since 2020.

Comment: Also, it looks like your issue is just a simple typo. You set `high = mid + 1` if the guess is too high, but you also set `low = mid + 1` otherwise. I'm pretty sure you meant `low = mid - 1`.

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a variable name. `list` is already a built-in name and overriding it will most likely cause you issues in the future.

Comment: i use python 3, in the book it was mentioned that (low + high)/2 would automatically round the result if it's not an integer. Thank you all for answers, will certainly look into learning how to used GUI :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- Use integer division (so it will work in Python 3): `mid = (low + high)//2`
- When `guess > item` you want to *exclude* the guessed value from the next range, but with `high = mid + 1` it still is *in* the range. Correct to `high = mid - 1`

Comment: it helped, however the problem was not in "high" equation, but in "low" one - it should be = mid -1, since we were trying to find an item that was not in a first half of the list, so with second iteration we start looking for it in another bigger half. But your answer gave me the right direction to look for, thanks

Comment: Note sure what you mean. See it run [here](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma667121945459839) with the two corrections I mentioned. Anyhow, happy to hear it worked out for you.